# No aparecen las consultas a bbdd (logback + ibatis)

Tags: sql, mybatis

estoy intentando que me salgan las trazas de las consultas a base de datos en mi logback y no lo consigo, todo lo que encuentro es para log4j. 
Esto es lo que tengo yo en estos momentos:

```
<appender name="FILE_JESUS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>jesus</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>jesus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>##|%date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} ~~ %X{IdSesionXLNetS} ~~ %X{IpXLNetS} ~~ %X{IdUsuarioXLNetS} ~~ %X{PuestoXLNetS} ~~ %X{sCodApp} ~~ %property{weblogic.Name} ~~ %X{subsistemaFuncional} ~~ %level ~~ %msg |## %n</Pattern>
        </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache.ibatis" level="debug"> 
    <appender-ref ref="db_log" /> 
</logger>
```

Necesito poder configurar para ver las sentencias. No se si en la parte del .xml (sqlMapper) hay que configurar algo,alguien me puede echar una mano?

Answer (score 0):

Al menos hasta la última versión publicada (3.5.0) no es posible configurar MyBatis para que soporte directamente logback. Según la documentación de MyBatis (http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/es/logging.html):

> MyBatis proporciona información de logging mediante el uso interno de una factoría. La factoría interna delega la información de logging en alguna de las siguientes implementaciones.
>
> SLF4J
> Apache Commons Logging
> Log4j 2
> Log4j
> JDK logging
>
> La solución de logging elegida se basa en una introspección en tiempo de ejecución de la propia factoría interna de MyBatis. La factoría usará la primera implementación de logging que encuentre (el orden de búsqueda es el de la lista de más arriba). Si no se encuentra ninguna, el logging se desactivará.

Sin embargo, es posible utilizar SLF4J que tiene un bridge para logback.

Comment: Si estas es una respuesta correcta, se podria haber puesto en comentarios. mira por favor [answer]

Comment: La respuesta es correcta. No entiendo que se vote negativo.